# Creating code to change bullet type based on current weapon held

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to this so bear with me, I am creating a game for class where I have 3 different weapons and I am creating 3 different bullets for each weapon. The weapons are different shapes, so a SphereGun, CubeGun, and TriangleGun, so each bullet is a different shape. I was able to create a weapon switching system which allows the player to change weapon using scrollwheel up and down, basically enabling the gameObject if it = the index number. However I have bullet shooting attached to my PlayerMovement script where it checks for if the fire key is being pressed and if so will shoot the weapon. I am wondering if there if a way, maybe using if else statements to check if the gameObject = a certain type and if so then instantiate that bullet type prefab? Basically asking if there is a way to change bullet type based on the weapon being held. I will attach my code below.
this is my WeaponSwitching Code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int previousthing = selectedWeapon;
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            else
                selectedWeapon++;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            else
                selectedWeapon--;
        }
        if (previousthing != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }
    }
    void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if (i == selectedWeapon)
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            else
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the bullet shooting aspect of my PlayerMovement script
Was thinking I could maybe add the if else statement within the shoot method here to change the weapon if it = the gameObject type or name of the Gun.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            shoot();
        }
    }
    void shoot()
    {
        GameObject g = Instantiate(bulletsph, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation)
               as GameObject;
        Destroy(g, 1.5f);
    }
```

Another solution I think may work in theory is to create a different script for shooting for each weapon type, so having 3 different scripts which will fire their respective type of bullet, although I think that is a long way of getting the solution, and am hoping there is a way where I can put it within one script.

I am also attaching screenshots of my project hierarchy layout.
[hiearchy layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDPbX.jpg)

Thanks for the help in advance. Please let me know if you have any questions that will help me to find a soluton :)

Comment: You already know what weapon is being used: `selectedWeapon`, you just need to pass that information to your bullet shooting script. Declare that script as a variable in your `WeaponSwitching` class, assign it in the inspector and add a line in the script to set a bullet type variable in the bullet script that then informs what type of bullet to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right you just want a state machine concept. So for example gun is a triangle then shoot a triangle. If this is the case it's pretty easy.

```cs
public class test
{



   public enum bulletTypes
   {
       Sqaure,
       Triangle,
       Cirlce,
   }

   public GameObject[] Bullets;
   public bulletTypes BulletType

   void shoot()
   {
       GameObject bullet = null;
       
       switch(BulletType){
           case BulletTypes.Sqaure:
            bullet = Bullets[0];
            break;
           case bulletTypes.Cirlce:
            bullet = Bullets[1];
            break;
           case BulletTypes.Triangle:
            bullet = Bullets[2];
            break;

       }
       
       GameObject g = Instantiate(bullet, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation)
              as GameObject;
       Destroy(g, 1.5f);
   }
}
```

And just change the BulletType Variable when you want to fire a different bullet. If something is not clear just contact me.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, this is probably an easier method than what I got but I basically just used the index of each gun, them being 0, 1 or 2 in the index and then had the shoot() method being the specifix type for each gun, so like If i = 0 then shoot the sphere bullet, if 1 then shoot the cube and so on.